# Deduplicate GitHub Workflow Check

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow that runs `on: deployment_status`.
The repo deploys both a web app and a Storybook app.
I have a check in my job for `contains(github.event.deployment_status.target_url, 'storybook')` which skips the job when the web app is deployed. Passes when the storybook tests succeed and fails when the Storybook tests fail.
However, as this action is run twice, the checks on the PR seem to only take in to account the skipped result.
Is there a way to skip the workflow (not just the job) so that the skipped result isn't reported?
Or is there a way to deduplicate the names of the workflows so that they are reported as separate checks in the PR?

Thanks